# Select the number of elements in each group before calculating the mean

Tags: python, pandas, pandas-groupby, apply

I have a dataframe df with one column only.
The data is monthly.
The data type is float.
The index is dates with the 'start of month' format.
Sample data is here

```
np.random.seed(167)
rng = pd.date_range('2000-01-01', periods=200, freq='MS')

df = pd.DataFrame(
    {"x": np.cumsum([np.random.uniform(-0.01, 0.01) for _ in range(200)])
    }, index=rng
)
```

I can obtain a dataframe with the monthly averages (i.e. twelve values, one for each month of the year) with this:

`df.groupby(df.index.to_series().dt.month).mean()`.

But I am trying to obtain the monthly averages across the last few years, for example the last three years.
I am trying this:

`df.groupby(df.index.to_series().dt.month).apply(lambda x: x.iloc[-3:]).mean()`

but it returns one single value rather than the desired dataframe with twelve values, one for each month of the year.

Comment: Can you add some sample data and expected ouput?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

First filter by [`DataFrame.last`](http://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/reference/api/pandas.DataFrame.last.html) and then use month periods by [`DatetimeIndex.to_period`](http://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/reference/api/pandas.DatetimeIndex.to_period.html) instead `month`s:

```
df = df.last('3Y')

df = df.groupby(df.index.to_period('m')).mean()
```

---

```
print (df)
                x
2014-01  0.033955
2014-02  0.024319
2014-03  0.021346
2014-04  0.029669
2014-05  0.032332
2014-06  0.029898
2014-07  0.031526
2014-08  0.031103
2014-09  0.035407
2014-10  0.036398
2014-11  0.027093
2014-12  0.027330
2015-01  0.022826
2015-02  0.023622
2015-03  0.023993
2015-04  0.029287
2015-05  0.036700
2015-06  0.037833
2015-07  0.028914
2015-08  0.031578
2015-09  0.025939
2015-10  0.020513
2015-11  0.013072
2015-12  0.006051
2016-01  0.010619
2016-02  0.008403
2016-03  0.017979
2016-04  0.017292
2016-05  0.026308
2016-06  0.032746
2016-07  0.033926
2016-08  0.041456
```

Or if no problem with datetimes:

```
df = df.last('3Y').resample('m').mean()
print (df)
                   x
2014-01-31  0.033955
2014-02-28  0.024319
2014-03-31  0.021346
2014-04-30  0.029669
2014-05-31  0.032332
2014-06-30  0.029898
2014-07-31  0.031526
2014-08-31  0.031103
2014-09-30  0.035407
2014-10-31  0.036398
2014-11-30  0.027093
2014-12-31  0.027330
2015-01-31  0.022826
2015-02-28  0.023622
2015-03-31  0.023993
2015-04-30  0.029287
2015-05-31  0.036700
2015-06-30  0.037833
2015-07-31  0.028914
2015-08-31  0.031578
2015-09-30  0.025939
2015-10-31  0.020513
2015-11-30  0.013072
2015-12-31  0.006051
2016-01-31  0.010619
2016-02-29  0.008403
2016-03-31  0.017979
2016-04-30  0.017292
2016-05-31  0.026308
2016-06-30  0.032746
2016-07-31  0.033926
2016-08-31  0.041456
```